# Ubuntu SDK - Custom executable

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I have a problem with Ubuntu SDK. I try to run project (qml and c++) but I get pop up window with message "Could not find the executable" and some settings (command, arguments, working directory)

How should I run it?

[image]

Comment: Still you can post pic in imgur and provide link here :)

Comment: Picture was added ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C++ program with a QML interface, *Command* is the name of the executable produced by compilation and *Arguments* is whatever arguments you want to pass it.

If you have a QML program with C++ plugins, *Command* is `qmlscene` and *Arguments* is what you would add to `qmlscene` to run your QML program.  As a minimum, you probably want something like `-I . main.qml`.  The `-I .` tells `qmlscene` to look for plugins in the current directory, and `main.qml` should be changed to whatever the name of your main QML file is.